# folder path when it has no files using OpenFileDialog in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

how to get the folder path if no file is present in that folder using OpenFileDialog Class in WPF

```
{
      Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlgObjDest = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
      dlgObjDest.Multiselect = true;
      dlgObjDest.DefaultExt = ".*";
      dlgObjDest.InitialDirectory = "c:";
      if (dlgObjDest.ShowDialog() == true)
      {
          txtDestTesting.Text = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dlgObjDest.FileName);
      }
}
```

but it cant get folder path when there is no file to select

Answer (score 2):

It would be impossible for the `ShowDialog()` to return `true` if no file has been selected.

If you set the `OpenFileDialog`'s `CheckFileExists` property to `true` first then the user can enter a file name that does not exist and then you would get the file path.

I think what you need is a `FolderBrowserDialog`, which is not built-in with WPF, but can be implemented like in this library:
[wpfdialogs](https://wpfdialogs.codeplex.com/)